# icinga2 service dependency check

Tags: icinga2

I have a very simple use case where I want to disable my check_cert service when httpd service is down. This is my httpd service template:

`apply Service "httpd" {
  import "generic-service"
  check_command = "check_httpd_service"
  command_endpoint = host.vars.client_endpoint
  assign where host.vars.client_endpoint && host.vars.myserver
 }`

And this is the cert check service:

`apply Service "check_cert" {
  import "generic-service"
  check_command = "check_ssl_certificate"
  command_endpoint = host.vars.client_endpoint
  assign where host.vars.client_endpoint && host.vars.myserver
}`

I tried this but still got an alert from the check_cert:

`apply Dependency "cert_http_depend" to Service {
  parent_service_name = "httpd"
  disable_checks = true
  disable_notifications = true
  assign where host.vars.client_endpoint && host.vars.myserver
  }`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You may need the state that the parent service should be:

```
parent_service_name = "httpd"
...
states = [ OK ]
```